# "Automation Error: Object Invoked has disconnected from its clients"

Tags: excel, vba

I figured out what Nick was suggesting, and the following is the error number & description that I'm getting:

> '-2147417848 (80010108)' Automation error The object invoked has
> disconnected from its clients

The line of code that is highlighted when I debug is:

```
.Rows(Lst).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

I thought that I had seen somewhere on this or another forum to unregister then re-register a specific file, but I was at home when I came across that, and didn't want to try it on my laptop, since everything already works 100% on it.

Once again, any help is greatly appreciated.  I leave Sunday for 2 weeks, and I really need to get this working before I leave.  Most of the people working for me are not excel guru's and need all buttons/functions working, as they won't be able to troubleshoot and/or work around the problems.

I am still sitting with the following code in a regular module, and the next set of code below that is in one of the worksheet modules.

```
 Sub add_InvRow()
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 Application.EnableEvents = False

 switch = "off"

 With ThisWorkbook
  Dim wb As Excel.Workbook, Lst As Long
  Set wb = Application.ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet, sw As Worksheet, os As Worksheet
   Set ws = ActiveSheet: Set sw = Application.Sheets(Sheet1.Name): Set os = Application.Sheets(Sheet4.Name)

  With ws
  Lst = ActiveCell.Row
  End With
 
   If ws.CodeName = "Sheet3" Then
 
  With os
   .Rows(213).Copy
  End With

  With ws
 

   .Rows(Lst).Insert Shift:=xlDown
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
     
    venTabForm.Show
  End With
End If

If ws.CodeName = "Sheet23" Then
 
  With sw
   .Rows(135).Copy
  End With

  With ws
  
   .Rows(Lst).Insert Shift:=xlDown
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
     
    cItemForm.Show
  End With
End If
 
 If ws.CodeName = "Sheet25" Then
 
 With sw
   .Rows(105).Copy
  End With

  With ws
   
   .Rows(Lst).Insert Shift:=xlDown
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
     
   coInvForm.Show
  End With
 End If
 
 If ws.CodeName = "Sheet28" Then
      
  With sw
   .Rows(100).Copy
  End With
  
  With ws
   
   .Rows(Lst).Insert Shift:=xlDown
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
     
   kInvForm.Show
  End With
End If

If ws.CodeName = "Sheet27" Then
  
  With sw
   .Rows(130).Copy
  End With
  
  With ws
     .Rows(Lst).Insert Shift:=xlDown
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
     
     ItemForm.Show
  End With
End If
 
If ws.CodeName = "Sheet22" Then
  
  With sw
   .Rows(120).Copy
  End With

  With ws
   
   .Rows(Lst).Insert Shift:=xlDown
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
     
    caInvForm.Show
  End With
End If
 
 Set ws = Nothing: Set sw = Nothing: Set os = Nothing: Set wb = Nothing
End With

 switch = "on"
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

This code is on one of the worksheets that has a command button, which calls the above code.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If switch = "off" Then Exit Sub
 If Target.Address = "$H$1" Then
  Call findItem
 Exit Sub
 End If


If Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("P:P")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Cells.Value = 0 Or Target.Cells.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, iNUM As String, kitSHT As Worksheet, ksRNG As Range, kITEM As Range, kbCELL As Range
Dim iNAME As String, catSHT As Worksheet, csRNG As Range, cbCELL As Range, cITEM As Range
Dim logCELL As Range



Set wb = ThisWorkbook: Set ws = wb.Sheets(Sheet27.Name): Set kitSHT = wb.Sheets(Sheet28.Name): Set catSHT = wb.Sheets(Sheet22.Name)
Set ksRNG = kitSHT.Range("C5:C1100"): Set kbCELL = ksRNG.Cells(5, 3)
Set csRNG = catSHT.Range("C6:C400"): Set cbCELL = csRNG.Cells(6, 3)


 If (Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:P")) Is Nothing)) And (Target.Cells.Count = 1) And (Target.Column = 16) Then
  If Target.Value = 0 Then Exit Sub
   iNUM = Target.Offset(, -12).Value
   iNAME = Target.Offset(, -10).Value

   If kitSHT.Cells.Find(What:=iNUM, After:=kbCELL, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) Is Nothing And _
  catSHT.Cells.Find(What:=iNUM, After:=cbCELL, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) Is Nothing Then



    MsgBox iNUM & "-" & iNAME & "" & " is not currently listed on" & " " & kitSHT.Name & " " & "or" & " " & catSHT.Name & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Please add" & " " & iNUM & "-" & iNAME & "" & " to" & " " & kitSHT.Name & " " & _
               "or" & " " & catSHT.Name & " " & "and corresponding count sheets", vbInformation
               
  Set wb = Nothing: Set ws = Nothing: Set kbCELL = Nothing
  Set ksRNG = Nothing: Set kitSHT = Nothing: Set cbCELL = Nothing: Set catSHT = Nothing: Set csRNG = Nothing
  Exit Sub
 Else
If Target.Value = 0 Then Exit Sub
  premNUM = iNUM


 pFORM.Show
 End If
 End If

  Set wb = Nothing: Set ws = Nothing: Set kbCELL = Nothing
  Set ksRNG = Nothing: Set kitSHT = Nothing: Set cbCELL = Nothing: Set catSHT = Nothing: Set csRNG = Nothing


  Set ksRNG = Nothing: Set kitSHT = Nothing: Set cbCELL = Nothing: Set catSHT = Nothing: Set csRNG = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: just as a first to try: better use `Application.EnableEvents = False` to prevent the worksheet-change... pls try it and tell if the error still pops... also try to avoit `select` (it messes up if used witn non-active worksheets). Like `.Rows(Lst).Select` and `Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown` will be `.Rows(Lst).Insert Shift:=xlDown` :)

Comment: In the Worksheet_Change event, you have both `If Target.Address = "$H$1"` and `If Target.Address <> "H1"` (i.e. inconsistent address formats - both should be $H$1). Using text comparisons here is not good practice - use [Application.Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff835030.aspx) instead, like this: `If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("H1")) Is Nothing) Then`

Comment: @barrowc - I agree with your advice but the test you propose is not the same test the OP is using...

Comment: Setting object variables to Nothing at the end of your procedures is not needed.

Comment: @Tim Williams - fair point - `If (Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("H1")) Is Nothing)) And (Target.Count = 1) Then` would be the same test

Comment: As per @DirkReichel comment, I would look into applying the Application.EnableEvents option as the using the 'switch' variable is likely where it messes up your process.

Comment: Thanks for input.  I will try these and let you know.  However, I've only had problems/errors while using my work computers, so I won't be able to truly test it until tomorrow morning.  It's really strange that it only gives errors at work, because I'm using the same OS & same version of Excel as I use on my home laptop, which has never given me an error.

Comment: This may be due to at work the workbook is shared and accesed by multiple users, or your worstation is used in a remote-way inside the network... also open from a network-drive is different for the OS itself... too, the OS itself is most likely NOT the same as the one you have at home...

Comment: I just tried this at work, and the error msg that I keep getting says:

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter and it posted my comment. The error message says        "Object Invoked has disconnected from its clients"       Then when I debug, it takes to the following line of code:                                  With ws
      .Rows(Lst).Insert Shift:=xlDown
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
         
        ItemForm.Show
      End With

Comment: It highlights the line:            .Rows(Lst).Insert Shift:=xlDown

Comment: Also, one final note, there is no shared drive.  All of these files are saved to my dropbox account, which I've installed on each work computer.  My home laptop is accessing this file the same way we do at work (via dropbox folder)

Comment: I have no idea what I'm doing wrong anymore.  Just to test, I saved this workbook as a different name, removed all code except for the module that copies & inserts row, and I still keep getting the same error.  I moved away from the ".select" and changed it back to the ".Rows(Lst).Insert Shift:=xlDown"           and I still keep getting the exact same error msg telling me that "THE OBJECT INVOKED HAS DISCONNECTED FROM ITS CLIENTS"

Comment: Yes that's what you need to do - divide and conquer and isolate the issue. Now you need to try a method that is more innocuous, something like `Debug.Print ws.Name` and then maybe `ws.Cells("A1") = 'TEST'` (don't know if that's correct syntax but you get the idea). Since you have many lines that cause the issue I suggest you now reduce your code to the minimum reproducible code and post it.

Comment: Also you might want to add `Debug.Print Err.Description` to your error handler. Error handlers that don't actually handle the error tend to mask and confuse the real issue.

Comment: Thanks again for the input.  I will play around with this again today.  However, I apologize, but I'm a little confused on where to place the "Debug.Print ws.Name"  or the "ws.Cells("A1") = 'Test' ".   I've pretty much taught myself VBA over the past 4-5 years through some books I purchased and through trial and error.  However, there is still quite a bit that confuses me.

Comment: Ok.  I did some research and discovered what Nick meant by Err.Description.  The error msg that I'm getting is as follows:

Comment: -2147417848     The Object invoked has disconnected from its clients.   I have no idea what else I can do?  I been online searching for solutions for the past 3+days, and cannot find one that works.  If anybody has any input and/or suggestions, please let me know..

Comment: I am going to post a separate question about this issue.  Since my last post/update, I've done the following:

Comment: Sorry... Hit enter again... since my last post/update, I've done the following:  1. Uninstalled/reinstalled Office   2. Tested on multiple computers, and it appears that it's only happening on 2 of my work computers, but the other15+ computers it works great       3.  Installed the same version of Windows and Office that was on other computes that this file worked on....    4. Finally broke down, paid $149 to Microsoft so they could remote in to my work computer and fix (still waiting for them to fix)

Comment: I believe that this issue has something to do with a windows file or setting, and not so much with the code.  My main account for work is a University, and I sent this to their computer/it/networking gurus, and the code worked perfectly on all of their computers.  They could not get it to break/error...   I'm going to answer this question by saying that this is not a VBA issue, and that I'm going to repost as a windows/office question...  Hopefully I'm doing the right thing here, as I did not want to leave this question open under the current "VBA-Excel" category

Comment: I am having the same problem. And my code is even simpler... Just one line: "ActiveSheet.Copy", then I get this exact same message and then Excel stops responding... But other codes are working fine... I tired to save the workbook as xls and run ActiveSheet.Copy, still got the same error... I'm running the VBA code on Excel 2007 32 bit and Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard...

Answer (score 7):

Ok... It's been well over 1 month now, and I've finally fixed this!! Fortunately & Unfortunately, it had absolutely nothing to do with my code.  Instead, it was an MS Office Vs. Windows 8 problem.  To fix it, I ran the compatability troubleshooter, and all is back to perfect again:

1. Open MS Excel (Any File or new file)
2. Pull up Task Manager
3. Click on MS Office or Excel Icon in Background Processes, Right click, and select properties
4. Under Compatibility, Click "Run Compatibility Troubleshooter"
5. When finished running, test file again, if it works right, click apply settings to this program. If it doesn't work, click next and choose from the options. (I chose that it worked in previous version of Windows (Windows 7) Then click Next again.
6. Test file again, and it worked.

I cannot believe that this is all I had to do the whole time! I actually spent $149 thinking that Microsoft Support could remote in and fix it, but that was an absolute waste!  I was transferred to 12+ different people/departments, and still got nothing from them.  I finally stumbled across the solution this morning....

Anyway, thanks to everyone who posted and tried to help me with this. I always log off of this site with better VBA skills than I signed on with because of all of you... So Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me:

Before adding rows with Shift:=xlDown delete bottom rows on the worksheet

```
'ADD THE ROWS YOU WANT

Sheets("XXXXXX").Range("A100000:A100100").EntireRow.Delete

With Selection
.Copy
.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your sheet is not protected with cells locked while doing insert.  This could be one of the reason why the code will fail.  This code was working for me on one folder, but when I copied the excel macro file to another folder I started getting this error.  Since it is only for formatting, I avoided using the below codes altogether and did formatting the usual way and not copying from above rows.
Note that in first code, entire row gets selected and if you have protected cells, it could lead to failure.
    'Rows(r + 3 & ":" & r + 3).Select
    'Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, with some macros that were working for everyone but not 1 person.

I solved it by asking the person to not use a folder that was synced to OneDrive, so be careful when using OneDrive.

I had other cases where OneDrive marked downloaded files from BOX or other file sharing services as read only, and made macros error out. And all you would need to do is open the file, save it and open it up again, but allot of people blamed it on my macros. It took me a while to find the cause, and to find a way to save an reopen the file using macros, before it actually opens...